# Not able to Identify element in Ruby-WATIR?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, watir

PAGE:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn auth-button" value="Submit">
```

WATIR CODE:

```
Then(/^I click on submit$/) do
  browser.button(:class,"btn auth-button").click
end
```

Exception:

```
Then I click on submit                                                                                   # Features/Step_definitions/ChefD.rb:178
      element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for true condition on #<Watir::Button: located: true; {:class=>"btn auth-button", :tag_name=>"button"}> (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
      ./Features/Step_definitions/ChefD.rb:179:in `/^I click on submit$/'
      features/Sanity_scenarios.feature:47:in `Then I click on submit'
```

Help me how to identify this element?

Comment: You might need to provide more details on how to reproduce the issue. A page with that exact HTML and that exact Watir code worked for me.

Comment: Hello @Justin Ko   

Below is the exact HTML for Reset password submit button , 
<div class="text-center">
              <p>
                <input type="submit" class="btn auth-button" value="Submit">
              </p>

              <button type="button" id="HideRecoverPasswordLink" class="text-link">Cancel</button>
            </div> 

however i can identitfy the Log in button element in the below HTML using the same WATIR code.

<div class="text-center">
            <input type="submit" class="btn auth-button" value="Log In">
        </div>

Comment: If you create a page with just that HTML does the problem actually occur? It still works for me. You likely need to consider more of the HTML of the page. Some things to check would be if the element is in another window, in an iframe, and if there are multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 btn = @browser.button value: 'Submit'
    btn.exists?
    btn.click
```